# is there an existing language model for calculating the probability of P(output|input), needed for aligning texts from OCR

Tags: language-models, optical-character-recognition

I have a bunch of boxes containing texts from receipt [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) results, and I need to a way to align them properly.

The attached photo shows part of a contrived receipt,

[image]

but it illustrates the problem I need to solve. Because the receipt image is slanted, the `Subtotal:` box is more aligned with `25` instead of `$23.00`, so if I just naively concatenate the boxes based on their horizontal positions, the output would be

```
$23.00
Subtotal: 25
# items:
```

while what I really want is

```
Subtotal: $23.00
# items: 25
```

I am thinking of using a language model to predict the probability of `p(25|Subtotal:)` and `p($23.00|Subtotal:)`, and then compare them, to decide proper alignment in addition to heuristics based on their relative positions. Does anyone know if there is a such a model already trained on large corpus that I can use directly?

Comment: This would be...any language model? If you want something fast and small, you could even find a KenLM model for English from someone who works on machine translation.